# iOS Printer Simulator

Tags: printing, ios-simulator, keychain

I'm trying to get Printer Simulator working with the iOS Simulator for testing printing, but I'm unable to do so. The preview area remains blank with a spinning wheel in it, and tapping Print closes the printing window without anything happening.

Notably, attempting to print produces the following in Printer Simulator's log:

```
[19/Sep/2018:03:34:58 -0400] [Client 1] Encrypting connection.
[19/Sep/2018:03:34:59 -0400] [Client 1] Unable to encrypt connection from 192.168.2.59: Unable to find server credentials.
```

(where the `Client` number starts at one and climbs to 6).

A little googling suggests that maybe some connection/permission/security issues may be in play, so I checked out Keychain to see (as one of the solutions suggests) if there's anything amiss there.

Now, I didn't actually *do* anything. But the next time I tried to print from my app in the Simulator with Printer Simulator running, I got the attached: "certtool wants to use the 'ssl' keychain."

[image: certtool wants to use the 'ssl' keychain.]

Except I've never heard of the "ssl" keychain. There is no ssl keychain in the Keychain utility. No password I would have used works, nor does an empty one.

And now, having restarted my app and Printer Simulator, I'm back to the original error(s), and the keychain message no longer appears.

Has anyone run into something like this before?